# Using B2C generated keys to sign IEF policy tokens

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

It appears that when using IEF I need to provide/generate my own signing key and provide it to the JwtIssuer TechnicalProfile through the 'issuer_secret' CryptographicKeys element. I would rather B2C used its own signing keys, which are generated much more frequently than I can do it manually, and which are still available via the JWKS endpoint. Is there a way to accomplish that? (or am I missing some significant reason why that's not how it works by default?)

Answer (score 1):

B2C will not use its signing keys for IEF policies for security reasons.

Applications use keys to verify whether a token was issued by a specific Security Token Service (STS). When presented with a token that makes certain claims about the user, how can that application be sure it should trust that token to be issued by B2C?

In IEF, the policy author has freedom to issue whatever claims they want about the user. Therefore, B2C MUST NOT sign those tokens because those claims may or may not be correct.

From a management perspective, the best way to think about this is that using IEF, you are creating your own custom Security Token Service (STS). And as part of STS, you have to manage the keys too.

(IEF could add tooling to make key rollover easier though, but it still must not use the same signing keys as B2C.)